# How to call function on button click where button is inside success method of .ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have .ajax() method i am getting json response from it successfully for each record i got i need to add a button when we click on it should call another function how can i do that.

```
$.ajax({
url: "ajs/index",
type: "GET",
dataType: "JSON",
success: function(data) {  
  var output=""
      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
           output += "name" + data[i].name
                  + "title: " + data[i].title
                  + "content: " + data[i].content
                  + "<input type='submit' class='delete' value='Delete' onclick='deleterecord("+data[i].id+");'><br>"


    }
     $("#result").html(output);
     $('#result').on('click', '.delete', deleterecord(id){
       alert("test")
       $.ajax({
                    url: "ajs/",
                    type: "DELETE", 
                    data: "22",     
                    dataType: "html",
                    success:function(data) { 
                        alert("success")
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("error")
                    }
                });
   }   //success function closed
 });
```

so when i click on that delete button which is in success function i need to call another function. I have created a function "delete record()" outside ajax call button it is not respondeing.can any one help me out.

Comment: Not sure what you meant but I think you should use `<button onClick='deleterecord()'></button>`  instead of using `<input type='submit' />`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll need to put a semi-colon `;` at the end of the line that you're adding data to `output` in.

I'd use a class to reference the click handler instead of binding onclick events to each element. You also **can't duplicate IDs** in HTML, and that will probably cause you issues. Again, use classes here.

Lastly, since you're concatenating the results of the array each time you iterate over it, you should set the HTML of `#result` after the loop instead of inside it. It will end up looking the same, but you'll end up with a number of useless calls that will only slow down the processing time.

Try this:

```
var output = '';

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    output += "name" + data[i].name
           + "title: " + data[i].title
           + "content: " + data[i].content
           + "<input type='submit' class='delete' value='Delete'><br>";
}

$("#result").html(output);
```

Then define your click handler using a [delegated approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) rather than direct:

```
$('#result').on('click', '.delete', deleterecord);
```

- To explain what happens above, you are listening for clicks that originate inside the `#result` element, and occur on elements with the delete class, and when they happen you're calling `deleterecord()`. This method listens past the original creation of the DOM, where direct events do not and need to be re-bound each time a new element is created. `click()` is a good example of a direct event, `live('click', function() {})` is a deprecated example of a delegated event.

I presume that inside your `deleterecord()` function you are correctly handling the processing of this, as you're using multiple submit buttons you should be returning false or using `preventDefault()` etc to stop the form submitting as normal. Something to think about if you haven't already... If this isn't what you mean to do then change your inputs for `<button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>` which won't send your browser anywhere by default.

Comment: As you mentioned i kept result and click handler out of the for loop. But if use handler as you mentioned it is not working

Comment: You either define a function, e.g. `deleterecord` in your click handler, or use an anonymous function e.g. `function(result){ alert(result); }` - don't do both as in your edited example